# Every time I run tmux, new ssh-agent child process is started (zshell)

Tags: linux, arch-linux, zsh, kde, tmux

Every time I start tmux or split tmux, new instance of ssh-agent is started ("Agent pid XXXX" appears on the top), which is quite annoying because I have to type the key password every time I want to use it. Not to mention the number of ssh-agents at the end of the day.

I'm using Arch Linux with KDE and my $SHELL is zshell.

`ssh-agent` starts automatically on system boot, but I can't figure out who starts it - it's not in the `.zshrc` or `.bash_profile`, I've tried to grep for 'ssh-agent' in the `~`but found nothing.

Comment: Does your `.zshrc` or `.profile` source any files in `/etc`?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, `tmux` spawns a login shell for all new windows. This would then source your `~/.zprofile` or wherever your start your `ssh-agent`.

As `man tmux` makes clear, you can avoid this behaviour by explicitly setting a default command in your `~/.tmux.conf`:

> default-command *shell-command*
>                      Set the command used for new windows (if not specified when the window is created) to *shell-command*, which may be any sh(1) command.
>                      **The default is an empty string, which instructs tmux to create a login shell using the value of the default-shell option**.

So, to prevent every new window being spawned as a login shell, add the following line to your config file:

```
set -g default-command /bin/zsh
```

Comment: I should have read the man page, thank you, it works :)

Comment: @nacholibre I thought you said none of your scripts in `~` ran `ssh-agent`. Did you miss `.zprofile`?